Sci-kit Learn Random Forest Regressor with CV produces R-squared less than 0
I'm utilizing random forest regressor to predict scores from a feature list of ~1200. My goal is to identify the top 30 features in the best model. However, I run into a problem where my average R-quared value across my 5 CV folds is negative. I guess that this means that my model would return a prediction that is worse than average, but I'm not really sure what I'd have to do to make it positive. I have utilized GridSearch to give clues as to hyperparameter tuning, as well as the CV implemention I mentioned before, but I'm stuck. Any assistance is much appreciated.
I have utilized GridSearch to give clues as to hyperparameter tuning, as well as the CV implemention I mentioned before, but I'm stuck, as I keep getting a negative R-squared. Any assistance is much appreciated. Here is my code:
PathModel = RandomForestRegressor(criterion='mse', random_state=28)

param_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [300],  # number of trees
    'max_depth': [150], 
    #'max_features': range(150, 300, 50),
    'min_samples_split': [200],
    'bootstrap': [True]
}

# Initialize KFold for cross-validation
kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=28)

# Initialize GridSearchCV
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=PathModel, param_grid=param_grid, 
                           cv=kfold, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', verbose=1, n_jobs=-1)

# Perform Grid Search to find the best parameters
grid_search.fit(x, y)

print("Best Parameters:", grid_search.best_params_)
print("Best Score (MSE):", -grid_search.best_score_)

# Get the best model from GridSearchCV
best_model = grid_search.best_estimator_

feature_importances = np.zeros(x.shape[1])
mse_scores = []
r2_scores = []

for train_index, test_index in kfold.split(x):
    x_train_fold, x_test_fold = x.iloc[train_index], x.iloc[test_index]
    y_train_fold, y_test_fold = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]

    best_model.fit(x_train_fold, y_train_fold)
    
    y_pred_fold = best_model.predict(x_test_fold)
    
    mse_fold = mean_squared_error(y_test_fold, y_pred_fold)
    r2_fold = r2_score(y_test_fold, y_pred_fold)
    
    mse_scores.append(mse_fold)
    r2_scores.append(r2_fold)
    
    fold_importances = best_model.feature_importances_
    feature_importances += fold_importances
    
mean_mse = np.mean(mse_scores)
mean_r2 = np.mean(r2_scores)
print("Average Cross-Validated MSE:", mean_mse)
print("Average Cross-Validated R-squared:", mean_r2)

